# Nested stl lists

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, std, stdlist

I want to make an array of lists that contain a list.

For example something like this

```
list<list<int>> L[5];
```

Obviously this code doesn't work in all compilers.

Which is the best way to create this kind of struct cause i think i am thinking wrong here.

Comment: What error message are you getting from your compiler?

Comment: It is not so obvious to me, you should provide more information about what is not working (compiler error, runtime error, wrong output, etc.).

Comment: @Luc the problem has to do with c++0x standards. It seems that some compilers are using some features by default. This causes this kind of problems when you have to compile your application with different compilers.

Comment: @unkulunkulu understood and that's what i did but what i say is true

Comment: I was not asking for the answer to your problem, I was advising you to better describe the issues you encounter so that we have enough information to help you. "Obviously doesn't work" is not an accurate description of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work and it's a possible approach to you task.

One guess is that `>>` should have a space in between for some compilers.

Like this:

```
list<list<int> > L[5];
```

Comment: It must have a space there for all non C++0x compatible compilers. MSVC supports `>>` as an extension from version 2005 or 2008 onwards.

Comment: @RedX: it is not a question of compatible. Current standard is C++ 2003, which defines >> as right-shift and nothing else. MSVC in that respect is not "compatible", but rather provides this as a non-portable extension to their compiler.

Comment: @messkech, you should rather add a space. You don't switch to C++ for example because `struct X { int a; }; X y;` doesn't compile in C, do you? Other way is to learn c++0x to full extent.